# Shuffling an array: Why does this work?

Tags: javascript, shuffle

I'm in the process of making a JavaScript solitaire game. I was looking for info on how to use `sort()` and `Math.random()` together in order to shuffle the deck when I happened upon this on CSS tricks:

```
array.sort(function() {return 0.5 - Math.random()})
```

Works beautifully, which is awesome, but I have no idea why. Would someone explain why this works?

Comment: `Works beautifully` It actually won't - the result will be biased. Better to assign a unique random value to each element first, and then sort on that value

Comment: @CertainPerformance Thank you for your comment, but if may critique it: this doesn't help me at all. Not only did you pointedly _not_ answer my actual question, but you managed to add at least 3 more questions to my initial one. Don't get me wrong, I want to understand all of it, but to reiterate: could you please direct me to some resource that would help me to understand? A link or something?

Comment: Check out the documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Comment: @CertainPerformance so I think I'm mostly gaining an understanding of the `.sort()` method based on the link you provided as well as @amateur_me 's answer, but now I'm interested in what you mean by biased?

Comment: Here's a discussion (with more links) on the bias of naive random sort: https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=2728914

Comment: right.... ya, I'll admit, I got a ways to go before I understand what they're talking about, but thanks for that! Bookmarked for later.

Comment: *I think I'm mostly gaining an understanding of the `.sort()` method based on the link you provided.* I'm puzzled by why you would not have read the documentation for `sort` before posting such a question. MDN is the definitive, authoritative JavaScript reference. Why would you post a question about `sort` without any idea of how it works?

Comment: @torazaburo Firstly, is there no use in starting a conversation? Secondly, I was initially seeking answers pertaining more so to the `0.5 - Math.random()` algorithm. It was only after I started reading the comments and docs that I realized I had incorrectly presumed `.sort()` was more straight-forward than it is.

Comment: @panrosmithe Please read the mission statement of SO very closely. It's not a place for conversations. Such places are called "forums". SO is not a forum. Forums facilitate conversations with features such as threads and responses to comments. The operating assumption with SO is that people do their homework before posting here, so that the questions that end up here are interesting, challenging, programming problems. In your particular case, a tiny bit of research would have shown both how the algorithm works, and why it is flawed.

Comment: I'm also confused because if you are referring to the CSS tricks page at https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/shuffle-array/, then the comment thread has comprehensive explanations of both **how** the `0.5 - Math.random()` trick works, and **why** it's a horrible idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**How Array.sort works**

In sort function, the array elements are sorted according to the return value of the compare function. If a and b are two elements being compared, then:

```
array.sort(function(a, b){return a - b});
```

Now, if (a-b) is less than 0, a is sorted to an index lower than b, as a is lesser than b.

If (a-b) returns 0, leave a and b unchanged with respect to each other, as they are equal.
Note: the ECMAscript standard does not guarantee this behaviour.

If (a-b) is greater than 0, b is sorted to an index lower than a, as a is greater than b.

**How Math.Random works**

It just returns a random value between 0 and 1.

Now coming to this case, since the actual values in the array are ignored here, and a random value is passed to (a-b) the function will just randomly return < 0, 0 or > 0 for every pair that gets compared. Hence the different sort order for same array.

Comment: I think I get this... so you could essentially write it kinda like this:
`for(i = 0; i < array.length; i++){`
`a = array[i];`
`b = array[i + 1];`
`if(a - b > 0){`
`array.splice(i + 1, 1);`
`array.splice(i, 0, b);}`
.. k, I don't think that would work, but it's the general concept, no? I guess I'm just curious how the compare function works, like.. ok, firstly, so when you simply do an `array.sort()` then the callback by default is the function you described right?

Comment: A simple array.sort does a string comparison rather than numeric comparison. You have to use the above for for numeric sorting.